# How to find the file-system location of a package?

Tags: package

Packages on my system are installed to `~/.config/emacs/elpa`,
although I assume it's possible to configure where packages are located.

How can I programmatically find the file-path for a package name (using a function call for example).

For example find: `/home/my_user_name/.config/emacs/elpa/company-lsp-20190612.1553` from the package name `company-lsp`.

Comment: `M-x describe-package`  -- you can expand the filename now that you know there is a built-in function that will give you `Status:  Installed in 'company-lsp-20190612.1553/'`

Comment: Is there an API call to do this?

Comment: The initial three (3) let-bound variables of `package-describe-package-1` will give you everything that you need ... PKG is a symbol.  `M-x find-function ...`

Comment: `package-describe-package-1` doesn't exist in latest master of emacs, or in `package-utils`

Comment: Ah `describe-package-1` is the thing I'm after.

Comment: Also consider `(find-library-name "company-lsp")`